# Ansible no longer works

Tags: python, linux, ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been learning Ansible on Windows 10 through WSL (using Pengwin, a Debian-based Linux) and it's been working fine up until last night. This morning, it's as though it doesn't exist any more:

```
❯ ansible
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 34, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'
```

Literally ***nothing*** has changed since last night. Even my computer has remained on. The only difference is that I had logged out of my terminal program.

I tried running `pengwin-setup` to re-install Ansible, but the issue persists.

Finally, I tried installing it via the instructions on Ansible's own site. However, things got even worse:

```
❯ sudo apt install software-properties-common
[sudo] password for sturm:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.20.2-2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 85 not upgraded.

❯ sudo apt-add-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpg2r1t8x7/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpg2r1t8x7/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 93C4A3FD7BB9C367: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ansible, Inc." imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 715, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 672, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 670, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 570, in update
    res = self._cache.update(fetch_progress, slist,
apt_pkg.Error: E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 168, in <module>
    if not sp.add_source_from_shortcut(shortcut, options.enable_source):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 759, in add_source_from_shortcut
    cache.update(sources_list=new_debsrc_entry.file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 573, in update
    raise FetchFailedException(e)
apt.cache.FetchFailedException: E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Now I'm out of options. How can I get Ansible running again?

Comment: Oh! Wait, you are using Ubuntu install instruction while on a Debian distro. You should follow the [how-to install it on Debian](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-debian) and not the [how-to install it on Ubuntu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu), or better yet, to be sure, install it via [pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-with-pip)

Comment: Also see https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Comment: Thank you, @β.εηοιτ.βε. Being such a newb, I was not aware of that much of a difference between Ubuntu and Debian. I went ahead and used the pip instructions you kindly linked to and was able to get ansible back installed and it appears to be running again. Please feel free to answer this question and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again! 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that you are using the instructions to install Ansible on an Ubuntu distribution, when, as you stated it, Pengwin is a Debian based one.

So you should use the chapter on [how to install Ansible on Debian](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-debian) and **not** [how to install Ansible on Ubuntu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu).

Better, still, because Pengwin is a very particular distribution, since it is a WSL one, you might want to try the installation via `pip`:

> Ansible can be installed with `pip`, the Python package manager. If
>   `pip` isn’t already available on your system of Python, run the
>   following commands to install it:
>
> ```
> $ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
> $ python get-pip.py --user
> ```
>
> Then install Ansible:
>
> ```
> $ pip install --user ansible
> ```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-with-pip

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for pointing out to me what should have been bleeding obvious. I bounce back and forth between various distros on my dev machine and the servers I ssh into, so I just got confused and used the wrong installation procedure. Thanks for helping me out with this. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/.local/bin/ansible-playbook", line 5, in <module>
    from ansible.cli.playbook import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'
```

after having installed Ansible with `pipx install ansible` as suggested by Debian 12 and Ubuntu 23.04.

What worked for me is `pipx install --include-deps ansible`.
Other solutions are discussed in the [pipx repo](https://github.com/pypa/pipx/issues/20) and in the [Ansible doc repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-documentation/issues/100).

Comment: same error after upgrade from Debian 11 => 12. pipx install --include-deps ansible doesn't change anything in my side.

Comment: This sounds like `ansible` is still pointing to an old Ansible install. What is the output of `which ansible`? Is it `~/.local/bin/ansible` (it should)? Is `~/.local/bin/ansible` a symbolic link pointing to `~/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/ansible` (it should)?